# How to handle 'Cancel' - django allauth linkedin

Tags: python, html, django

I am using allauth Django pacakge for linkedin authentification.

The login is working succesfully, the problem I have is when the user chooses to **Cancel** the authetification.
Then user gets redirected to this URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/linkedin_oauth2/login/callback/?error=user_cancelled_login&error_description=The+user+cancelled+LinkedIn+login&state=1BOK8XL2Xu3R

Which generates the authentification error which it's normal, I believe:

```
Social Network Login Failure
An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account.

{'provider': 'linkedin_oauth2', 'code': 'unknown', 'exception': None}
```

How can I treat/avoid this error in order to have an errorless flow ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the option to override the 'authentication_error' behavior by creating a custom
adapter:
**project_name/project_name/adapter.py**

```
class CustomSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def authentication_error(self,
                             request,
                             provider_id,
                             error=None,
                             exception=None,
                             extra_context=None):
        raise ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account_login')))
```

**settings.py**

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'jurisdiction.adapter.CustomSocialAccountAdapter'
```